# Всплывающее окно в дополнительном потоке

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, qprocess, qmessagebox

Сделал лаунчер для *ТЛ*. Написан на *PyQt5*. 
Разрабатываю если *ТЛ* не установлен, выдаю всплывающее окно, 
а т.к. у меня включен поток `threading` либо ошибка, либо белый экран ошибки и все виснет.

Помогите исправить.

```
import unit
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import time
import mouse
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import threading


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, unit.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

    self.setupUi(self)
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.jpg'))

    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)

def go(self):
    try:
        ff = os.getcwd()
        ff += '\\TLauncher.exe'
        os.startfile(ff)
        time.sleep(20)
        mouse.move(1102, 827)
        time.sleep(1)
        mouse.click('left')
    except:
        error = QMessageBox()
        error.setWindowTitle("Установите TL!")
        error.setText("Установите TLauncher. Без него майнкрафт не будет запускаться!")
        error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        error.exec()
    
def start_thread(self):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.go, args=())
    thread.start()


App = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
App.exec()
```

Comment: в Qt imho самый лучший способ вызывать GUI из неглавного потока, это `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` с параметром `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` или `Qt::QueuedConnection`, это на c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя взаимодействовать с виджетами в дополнительных потоках.

Я предложу вам попробовать использовать класс `QProcess`.
Класс [**QProcess**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) используется для запуска внешних программ и взаимодействия с ними.

1. `exePath = "C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. `exePath = "C:/Windows/system32/calc123.exe"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import sys
import os
import time
# ??? import mouse
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# ??? import unit                                 # from unit import Ui_MainWindow


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):              # ??? , unit.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
# ???    self.setupUi(self)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start', self.centralwidget) 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, alignment = Qt.AlignBottom)

    def start_thread(self):
        try:

        
#            exePath = "C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe"
#           нет такого exe`ка ------------>    vvv
            exePath = "C:/Windows/system32/calc123.exe"
            
            ret = QProcess.startDetached(exePath)        
            if not ret:
                raise
        except Exception as e:
            error = QMessageBox()
            error.setWindowTitle("Установите TL!")
            error.setText(
                "Установите TLauncher. Без него майнкрафт не будет запускаться!"
            )
            error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            error.exec()

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.jpg'))
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает

Comment: @АртемШвец пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour